# Disable a button based on text field values in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a requirement where there are multiple text boxes and drop down fields in my UI. I need to enable a button on UI when one of the multiple field has values. I am calling a function based on the ngModel values given for these fields but somehow the disable property value never changes based on the values when a drop down is selected, its always the same old value, the property value does not change.

HTML code goes like this

```
<button [disabled]="searchButtonStatus(x,y, z, a, b,
             c, d, e, f, g,
               h, i, j)" </button>






<tbody class="position cell-height">
    <tr>
      <td class="empty-cell" id="checkbox" ></td>
      <!--Funding status-->
      <td class="input-cell" id="status">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <select [(ngModel)]="x" (ngModelChange)="onSelectStatus(selectedStatus)" name="status"
                  class="form-control form-textbox input-sm">
            <option *ngFor="let statoption of options"  [value]="x" >{{ x}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <!--Loan certification-->
      <td class="empty-cell input-cell" id="certified">
        <div class="dropdown ">
          <select [(ngModel)]="y" (ngModelChange)="onSelectCertStatus(selectedCertStatus)" name="certStatus"
                  class="form-control form-textbox input-sm" style="width: auto;">
            <option *ngFor="let z of certOptions"  [value]="z" >{{ certoption }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <!--Manual hold-->
      <td class="empty-cell" id="hold">
        <div class="dropdown" style="">
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedHold" (ngModelChange)="onHoldFilter(selectedHold)" name="selectHold"
                  class="form-control form-textbox input-sm" style="width:auto;">
            <option *ngFor="let holdoption of holdOptions"  [value]="holdoption" >{{ holdoption }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <!--Batch ID-->
      <td class="input-cell">
        <input class="form-control form-textbox input-text"
               id="requestID"  [(ngModel)]="a" name="batch">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-glyph"></span>
      </td>
      <!--Seller Number-->
      <td class="empty-cell" id="seller">
        <input class="form-control form-textbox input-text " name="serialNo"
               id="sellerNumber" [(ngModel)]="b" style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-glyph"></span>
      </td>

      <td class="input-cell">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" id="lender_name"
               [(ngModel)]="c" name="c" style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-glyph"></span>

      </td>

      <td>
        <input class="form-control form-textbox input-text"
               id="d" [(ngModel)]="d" name="d" style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-glyph"></span>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input class="form-control form-textbox input-text" id="e"
               [(ngModel)]="e" name="e">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-glyph"></span>
      </td>

      <td class="input-cell">
        <my-date-range-picker  name="ngModelDateRange" id="sub_dt" [options]="myDateRangePickerOptions"
                               [(ngModel)]="f"></my-date-range-picker>
      </td>

      <td class="input-cell">
        <my-date-range-picker  name="ngModelDateRange" id="schd_fnd_dt" [options]="myDateRangePickerOptions"
                               [(ngModel)]="g"></my-date-range-picker>
      </td>


        </div>
      </td>
```

And on disable property I call this function which always returns the same value

```
searchButtonStatus(fndgStatTyp,lnCrtfnStatTyp,fndgHldInd,fndgSmssBchId, prtyRoleAltId,
                     lglEntyFullNme, ddfLnId, lnAltId, uiFndgSmssDttm, uiFndgSchdDt,
                     busEvntTypEffDt, finsDwlTyp, fndgColtUpbAmt){
    const value:Boolean = !(fndgStatTyp == null || lnCrtfnStatTyp ==null || fndgHldInd == null ||fndgSmssBchId == null || prtyRoleAltId == null ||
      lglEntyFullNme == null || ddfLnId == null || lnAltId == null || uiFndgSmssDttm == null || uiFndgSchdDt == null ||
    busEvntTypEffDt == null || finsDwlTyp == null || fndgColtUpbAmt == null)
    return value;
  }
```

Comment: Could you show your component code as well?

Comment: last piece of code is the component code

Comment: is that the only code left in the component? If so, then how do you set the values for `x`, `y`, `a`, `b`,`...` initially?

Comment: x,y,z etc values are set through ngModel

Comment: Where are those values (in my previous comment) defined in the component? The `[()]` operator sets the 2-way binding on something like `[(ngMdel)]="x"` where the value initially is set from `x` (where is it defined initially) to the `ngModel` directive. Also, if you are explicitly calling `(ngModelChange)` on the same `tag` then why are you also assigning `()` (paranthesis) as well to `[(ngModel)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vVFZFD3qqFvOhebD4CQw?p=preview) and changed some code.

```
<option *ngFor="let statoption of options"  [value]="x" >{{ x}}</option>
```

to:

```
<option *ngFor="let statoption of options" >{{ statoption}}</option>
```

Comment: This works I was able to use all the values instead to disable property instead of calling the function and then returning true/false